# PHP - Create array with number to string

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have this method for creating a simple json in php

```
$array = array_merge($array, array($cf => $nome));  
echo json_encode( $array );
```

And it work only if `cf` is not a number ex:

```
$cf = "12345";
$nome = "ASDS";
```

result is:

```
["ASDS"]
```

But if i change cf in "AS123" result is:

```
{AS123:ASDS}
```

The full code is:

```
while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $query ) ) {
        $cf = $row[ "cf" ];
        $nome = $row[ 'nome' ];
        $array = array_merge($array, array($cf => $nome));  
    }
    echo json_encode( $array );
```

Now i need convert this `cf` and `nome` in string because i have some problem with number and space, i can't change the json structure because is API of some application.

I think the final result should be with quotes like:

```
{"AS123":"ASDS"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think you need `array_merge`, you can just do something like:

```
$array = array();

while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $query ) ) {
        $cf = $row[ "cf" ];
        $nome = $row[ 'nome' ];
        $array[$cf] = $nome;  
}

echo json_encode( $array );
```

This will result to:

```
{"12345":"ASDS"}
```

Comment: Thanks so much =)

Comment: Happy to help :)